# Property 'studentList' is missing in type 'StudentInfo[]' but required in type 'StudentInfoProps'.ts(2741)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-typescript

Thanks in advance for your help with this error in Typescript.

I have the following types defined.
**StudentInfo.tsx**:

```
export type StudentInfo = {
  name: string;
  course: string;
};

export type StudentInfoProps = {
  studentList: StudentInfo[];
};

export type RootStackParamList = {
  ReactNative: {studentList: StudentInfoProps};
};
```

and this is the **App.tsx** where I am getting error in `{studentList:`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import {StudentInfoProps, RootStackParamList} from './types/StudentInfo';

export default function App(props: StudentInfoProps): React.JSX.Element {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="ReactNative">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ReactNative"
          component={HomeScreen}
          initialParams={{studentList: props.studentList}} // studentList showing error Property 'studentList' is missing in type 'StudentInfo[]' but required in type 'StudentInfoProps'.ts(2741)
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

In the default router, I get also error in studentList:

**HomeScreen.tsx**:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Pressable} from 'react-native';
import type {NativeStackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import StudentsScreen from './StudentsScreen';
import {StudentInfoProps} from '../types/StudentInfo';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  ReactNative: {studentList: StudentInfoProps};
};

type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'ReactNative'>;

export default function HomeScreen({route}: Props): React.JSX.Element {
  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const {studentList} = route.params;
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Pressable
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => {
            setIsPressed(true);
          }}>
          <Text> Check Student List</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      <View>
        {isPressed && <StudentsScreen studentList={studentList} />} //Type 'StudentInfoProps' is missing the following properties from type 'StudentInfo[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2740)
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

In the above HomeScreen, I am expecting studentList to be StudentInfoProps. Printing this variable the content is the following:

```
{"studentList":["{\"name":\"John Doe\",\"course\":\"Javascript\"}","{\"name\":\"Jane Doe\",\"course\":\"Typescript\"}"]}
```

During destructuring, I can define the type for studentList as follows:

```
const {studentList}: StudentInfoProps = route.params
```

The above gives me an error:

```
 Type 'Readonly<{ studentList: StudentInfoProps; }>' is not assignable to type 'StudentInfoProps'.
  Types of property 'studentList' are incompatible.
    Type 'StudentInfoProps' is missing the following properties from type 'StudentInfo[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2322)
```

**StudentsScreen.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';
import Student from '../components/Student';
import {StudentInfoProps} from '../types/StudentInfo';

export default function StudentsScreen({studentList}: StudentInfoProps) {
  return studentList?.map(student => {
    const {name, course} = JSON.parse(student);
    return (
      <Student
        key={uuidv4()}
        name={name}
        course={course}
      />
    );
  });
}
```

The above `StudentsScreen` component is expecting the list of students to iterate over it. Then, the type should be `StudentInfoProps`
Would you know how to solve those errors in `studentList` definition?

Thanks a lot

Comment: in App.tsx you do not have to provide props.studentList, just send props: initialParams={{studentList: props}}.
Still the second error would appear. For that, the StudentsScreen.tsx is needed in the question.